# Asymmetric Decryption RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding in .net with PEM file

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

I have a requirement wherein encryption takes place in Java and decryption takes place in .net as there are two systems. I'm struggling to perform asymmetric decryption.

On Java, asymmetric encryption is applied with "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"

```
public String encryptSymmKey() throws  Exception
 {
    Cipher asymmCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");     
    asymmCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, cert.getPublicKey());     
    byte[] encSymmKeyBytes = asymmCipher.doFinal(symmKey.getEncoded());   
    String encSymmKeyString= new String(Base64.encode(encSymmKeyBytes));     
    encSymmKeyString = URLEncoder.encode(encSymmKeyString, "UTF-8");  
    return(encSymmKeyString);
}
```

My task is to decrypt it and get back the actual symmetric key so that I can use it for Symmetric Decryption. I have a PEM file and a base64 password. I have tried to decrypt in two approaches via BouncyCastle and RSA(System.Security.Cryptography).

Approach 1:- RSA

Code:-

```
public class MyRSAParams
    {
      public static MyRSAParams fromRSAParameters(RSAParameters key)
      {
       var ret = new MyRSAParams();
       ret.Modulus = new BigInteger(key.Modulus.Reverse().Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray());
       ret.privExponent = new BigInteger(key.D.Reverse().Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray());
       ret.pubExponent = new BigInteger(key.Exponent.Reverse().Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray());
       return ret;
        }
        public BigInteger Modulus;
        public BigInteger privExponent;
        public BigInteger pubExponent;
       }
        public byte[] plainDecryptPriv(byte[] data, RSAParameters key)
        {
            MyRSAParams myKey = MyRSAParams.fromRSAParameters(key);
            return rsaOperation(data, myKey.privExponent, myKey.Modulus);
        }

            private byte[] rsaOperation(byte[] data, BigInteger exp, BigInteger mod)
            {
                BigInteger bData = new BigInteger(
                    data    //our data block
                    .Reverse()  //BigInteger has another byte order
                    .Concat(new byte[] { 0 }) // append 0 so we are allways handling positive numbers
                    .ToArray() // constructor wants an array
                );
                return
                    BigInteger.ModPow(bData, exp, mod) // the RSA operation itself
                    .ToByteArray() //make bytes from BigInteger
                    .Reverse() // back to "normal" byte order
                    .ToArray(); // return as byte array

                /*
                 * 
                 * A few words on Padding:
                 * 
                 * you will want to strip padding after decryption or apply before encryption 
                 * 
                 */
            }
```

Main Decryption Logic:-

```
    byte[] cipherBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
       using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
       using (var stream = File.OpenRead(<PEM FILE>))
       using (var reader = new PemReader(stream))
       {
        var rsaParameters = reader.ReadRsaKey();
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
       } 
       var decBytes = plainDecryptPriv(cipherBytes, rsa.ExportParameters(true));
       var decData = decBytes.SkipWhile(x => x != 0).Skip(1).ToArray();
       var result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(decData);
```

Result:- I got a string but it is incorrect

```
"\0�{]*ɠ8��+\0gNqMNm�hZ�\u001et\u0010��\u0010\u00161��u,*O��a�\u0003`8Iŝ���`]\u0003�a��A\\�\fiK�12��M� qOF�\u000e��Q\"Eg���3_�;��u�\u0011U\u0001����t�`����!56�,\a{�Z��\u0006|��K2}�HA�\b_�Ix\u0001]�ܳ��CW�;q\u001c�nJ<A�L�$�NG�u%\u001e4N�x��dl\u0011bS��X\u000f\u0006���\u0011�)�d�RW�E�\tB���5|��8���\u0014�(u]�ċ�o�*\u0016���P��z�\v����lء\u0017WYj�D2GT�t\u000f��p\u000f"
```

I have also tried with `rsa.Decrypt(cipherBytes, false)` and all other `RSAEncryptionPadding` options, the error that I see is:

> Parameter is incorrect

Approach 2:- BouncyCastle

Code:-

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(<PEM File>))
            {
                keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new 
Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(reader)).ReadObject();

                RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privKey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.Private;
                RsaKeyParameters privParameters = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(privKey.Modulus, 
privKey.PublicExponent, privKey.Exponent, privKey.P, privKey.Q, privKey.DP, privKey.DQ, 
privKey.QInv);
                IAsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

                eng.Init(false, privParameters);

                byte[] encdata = System.Convert.FromBase64String(ks);
                encdata = eng.ProcessBlock(encdata, 0, encdata.Length);
                string finalResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encdata);
            }
```

Result:- I get an error at `eng.ProcessBlock` saying the

> block is incorrect

I have also added password to `PemReader` and when tried it gave the same result.

I have made sure that I'm using the right PEM file. I'm using asp.net core version 3.0.

EDIT:-

[image: I see the bitlength of Modulus being 2048 which is 256 bytes, same as the cipher bytes]

Comment: hi, are you trying to retrieve the private key from the certificate ?

Comment: You are forgetting to undo the URL encoding of the base64 input in the second example. Check `encdata.length`, it must be the same as the key size in bytes.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have used byte[] encdata = System.Convert.FromBase64String(ks), which decodes the encoded string to bytes, and I'm using this bytes to process, but the error says block incorrect. The size of encData.Length is 256 bytes. I'm not sure on how to check the keysize. Can you please help me out.

Comment: To get an estimation, just ask the size in bits (BitLength) or bytes of the modulus. The byte size is generally the size in two-complements, so it may be 1 byte too large. Since you have `privKey.Modulus` anyway...

Comment: Please provide:
1) sample cert with password (or private key)
2) Sample string cipher and raw values

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I see the modulus has bitlength of 2048. I have posted an snap of it in the question post. Even the cipher bytes encdata.Length says 256. What else could be the issue other than a right private key? Please help me out.

Comment: @zaitsman unfortunately the key is confidential to share.

Comment: @user3312962 did you see i said `SAMPLE` cert.

Comment: @Clint I'm trying to decrypt the cipher text with private key, this is an asymmetric decryption. As per the way the encryption was coded in Java, I'm trying to decrypt the encrypted text with the given PEM file in all possible ways. I'm able to get some messy text with RSA, but with BouncyCastle I'm getting an error "Block is incorrect".

Comment: @zaitsman I saw that. I'm little new to cert and keys. I'll generate a sample cert with the available PEM file.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Not sure if it helps, I just check the inputblocksize and outputblocksize of encData object. Input says 256, output says 245. Is there any issue with the PEM file that I'm using, Do I need to take off  the header and a footer saying -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
and replace \n to empty, to read the actual keycontent as one string? Does that help?

Comment: No, that's part of the PEM. Yes, the inputBlocksize is the size of the modulus, the outputBlocksize is 11 bytes shorter than that due to PKCS#1 padding (minimal) overhead.